# How do you synchronize related collections in Cosmos Db?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My application need to support lookups for invoices by invoice id and by the customer. For that reason I created two collections in which I store the (exact) same invoice documents:

- `InvoicesById`, with partition key `/InvoiceId`
- `InvoicesByCustomerId`, with partition key `/CustomerId`

Apparently you should use partition keys when doing queries and since there are two queries I need two collections. I guess there may be more in the future.

Updates are primarily done to the `InvoicesById` collection, but then I need to replicate the change to `InvoicesByCustomer` (and others) as well.

*Are there any best practice or sane approaches how to keep collections in sync?*

I'm thinking change feeds and what not. I want avoid writing this sync code and risk inconsistencies due to missing transactions between collections (etc). Or maybe I'm missing something crucial here.

Comment: Change Feed is made for this scenario. Check it out here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-design-patterns

Comment: "since there are two queries I need two collections" -- this isn't really the case. You always want to query within a known partition if possible, but queries without specified PK will go across partitions with somewhat higher cost. Worth testing this before assuming multiple containers and copies are worthwhile.

Comment: It's very likely that the extra cost and overhead of managing several collections is not warranted. If you don't supply a partition key with a query, the cost for the query is multiplied by the number of physical partitions. If the collection has less than 10 GB of data *and* you have *never* set its throughput to more than 10 kRU/s, you will only have one physical partition, so it wouldn't make any difference whether you supply a partition key or not.

Comment: @Mo B.: Just found that Microsoft says if you have more than 100GB in the collection, then try to avoid cross partition queries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-query-container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change feed will do the trick though I would suggest to take a step back before brute-forcing the problem.

---

Please find detailed article describing split issue here: [Azure Cosmos DB. Partitioning.](https://medium.com/codex/azure-cosmos-db-partitioning-bc851a404476)

Based on the Microsoft recommendation for maintainable data growth you should select partition key with highest cardinality (in your case I assume it will be `InvoiceId`). For the [main reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview):

> Spread request unit (RU) consumption and data storage evenly across all logical partitions. This ensures even RU consumption and storage distribution across your physical partitions.

You don't need creating separate container with `CustomerId` partition key as it won't give you desired, and most importantly, maintainable performance in future and might result in physical partition data skew when too many Invoices linked to the same customer.

To get optimal and scalable query performance you most probably need `InvoiceId` as partition key and indexing policy by `CustomerId` (and others in future).

There will be a slight RU overhead (definitely not multiplication of RUs but rather couple additional RUs per request) in consumption when data you're querying is distributed between number of physical partitions (PPs) but it will be neglectable comparing to issues occurring when data starts growing beyond 50-, 100-, 150GB.

---

Why `CustomerId` might not be the best partition key for the data sets which are expected to grow beyond 50GB?

Main reason is that Cosmos DB is designed to scale horizontally and provisioned throughput per PP is limited to the `[total provisioned per container (or DB)] / [number of PP]`.

Once PP split occurs due to exceeding 50GB size your max throughput for existing PPs as well as two newly created PPs will be lower then it was before split.

So imagine following scenario (consider days as a measure of time between actions):

1. You've created container with provisioned 10k RUs and `CustomerId` partition key (which will generate one underlying PP1). **Maximum throughput per PP is `10k/1 = 10k RUs`**
2. Gradually adding data to container you end-up with 3 big customers with C1[10GB], C2[20GB] and C3[10GB] of invoices
3. When another customer was onboarded to the system with C4[15GB] of data Cosmos DB will have to split PP1 data into two newly created PP2 (30GB) and PP3 (25GB). **Maximum throughput per PP is `10k/2 = 5k RUs`**
4. Two more customers C5[10GB] C6[15GB] were added to the system and both ended-up in PP2 which lead to another split -> PP4 (20GB) and PP5 (35GB). **Maximum throughput per PP is now `10k/3 = 3.333k RUs`**

[image]

> **IMPORTANT**: As a result on `[Day 2]` `C1` data was queried with up to 10k RUs
> but on `[Day 4]` with *only* *max to 3.333k* RUs which directly impacts execution time of your query

*This is a main thing to remember when designing partition keys in current version of Cosmos DB (12.03.21).*

---

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a good solution. Different queries requires different Partition Keys on different Cosmos DB Containers with same data.

How to sync the two Containers: use Triggers from the firs Container.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/synchronizing-azure-cosmos-db-collections-for-blazing-fast-queries/

Cassandra has a Feature called Materialized Views for this exact problem, abstracting the sync problem. Maybe some day same Feature will be included on Cosmos DB.